# C++ Returning a string through an accessor

Tags: c++, string, class, accessor

I am trying to use an accessor to output information from my class to the console through the main(). However, I am unsure how to return my output without a return value or a return value that contains my output. Any help would be appreciated..

```
string WorkTicket::showWorkTicket(int ticketNumber, string clientID, int day, int month, int year, string description) const
 {


system("cls");
cout << setw(10) << "Ticket # : " << ticketNumber << endl;
cout << setw(10) << "Client ID : " << clientID << endl;
cout << setw(8) << "Date : "<< day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl;
cout << setw(10) << "Description : " << description << endl;


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string stream like [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) instead of `std::cout` to build your string in memory instead of printing it. For example:

```
std::string make_string_from_stuff(int x, float y, const std::string& name) {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "[" << x << ", " << y << "] : '" << name << "'";
    return oss.str();
}
```

will build a string like `[1, 2.5] : 'Joe'`